# Rsa decription with same key pair doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, cng

I am working on a cryptographic app in C# with .NET Framework. One of it's functions is to let the user store an (or multiple) RSA asymmetric key pair in the Windows KSP, export the public key to a BLOB and decrypt messages (in fact, it will use RSA only to encrypt/decrypt a symmetric key) encrypted with that one specific key. I am using the CNG implementation in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace.

In order to test it's functionality, I have created a keypair and given it a name. After that, I have exported the key using the following function:

```
public static byte[] GetPublicKeyBlob(string keyContainerName)
            {
                try 
                {
                    if (!CngKey.Exists(keyContainerName))
                        throw new CryptographicException($"The Key Service Provider does not contain a key with the name: '{keyContainerName}'");
                    cngKey = CngKey.Open(keyContainerName);
                    rsa = new RSACng(cngKey) { KeySize = keySize };
                    return rsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return null;
                }
            {
```

The (static) fields are the following:

```
public static RSACng rsa;
public static CngKey cngKey;
public static int keySize = 2048;                                                           // used
public static RSAEncryptionPadding rsaEncryptionPadding = RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512;  // later
```

Next, I used the following function to encrypt some sample data:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key)
            {
                byte[] output = null;
                try
                {
                    cngKey = CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);
                    rsa = new RSACng(cngKey) { KeySize = keySize };

                    if (input != null) 
                        output = rsa.Encrypt(input, rsaEncryptionPadding);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                return output;
            }
```

I took the output (which looked like a normal output for a cryptographic function) and used it as an input for the `Decrypt` function:

```
public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input, string keyContainerName)
            {
                byte[] output = null;
                try
                {
                    if (!CngKey.Exists(keyContainerName))
                        throw new CryptographicException($"The Key Service Provider does not contain a key with the name '{keyContainerName}'");

                    cngKey = CngKey.Open(keyContainerName);
                    rsa = new RSACng(cngKey) { KeySize = keySize };

                    if(input != null)
                        output = rsa.Decrypt(input, rsaEncryptionPadding);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                return output;
            }
```

Here, `rsa.Decrypt(input, rsaEncryptionPadding)` threw an exception with the message: "The parameter is incorrect.".
I wrote another `Encrypt` function using the saved key itself, as it follows:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, string publicKeyContainerName, bool setCngKey = true)
            {
                byte[] output = null;
                try
                {
                    if (setCngKey)
                    {
                        if (!CngKey.Exists(publicKeyContainerName))
                            throw new CryptographicException($"The Key Service Provider does not contain a key with the name: '{publicKeyContainerName}'");

                        cngKey = CngKey.Open(publicKeyContainerName);
                    }
                    rsa = new RSACng(cngKey) { KeySize = keySize };

                    if (input != null) 
                        output = rsa.Encrypt(input, rsaEncryptionPadding);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                return output;
            }
```

The same function for decryption was used with the same result.

At this moment I am stuck and I do not know what to do to solve this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that you're using `GenericPublicBlob`, so the blob doesn't have the private key needed for decryption.

Comment: Indeed. But the blob is used only for encryption, so it won't need the private key to work (if you look carefully, `Decrypt` does not have any blob). Somebody would need to encrypt the data without knowing the private key. Furthermore, I have create the last function which does not use any blob at all, but the keyPair in the KSP itself to overcome this possible flaw.

Comment: Indeed - I missed that crucial detail, sorry.